# Android Custom Spinner: Check Radio Button on Select

Tags: android, radio-button, spinner, adapter

I've created a custom adapter for my spinner because I wanted to have multiple rows. However, I would basically like to recreate androids spinner model with the radio button that gets selected when a spinner item is selected. Everything is working fine except I don't understand how to check the radio button when a list item is selected.

My SimpleCursorAdapter Custom Adapter code:

```
    @Override
public View newDropDownView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    super.newDropDownView(context, cursor, parent);

    View view = View.inflate(context, R.layout.grain_spinner_row, null);
    int nameColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex("name");
    String getName = cursor.getString(nameColumn);
    TextView name = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.GrainSpinnerName);
    name.setText(getName);

    int loviColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex("lovibond");
    String getLovi = cursor.getString(loviColumn);
    TextView lovi = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.GrainSpinnerLovibond);
    lovi.setText(getLovi);

    int gravityColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex("gravity");
    String getGravity = cursor.getString(gravityColumn);
    TextView gravity = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.GrainSpinnerGravity);
    gravity.setText(getGravity);

    rb = (RadioButton)view.findViewById(R.id.GrainSpinnerRadio);

    return view;
}

public static void toggleRadio(){
    if(!(rb.isChecked())){
        rb.toggle();
    }
}
```

OnSelectedItemChanged code:

```
        @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
        //Collects the id from the currently selected item so we can use that to reference the ingredient in the recipe database.
        //Because we are using a SimpleCursorAdapter to populate nameSpinner, we must use a cursor to request currentName.
        Cursor cc = (Cursor)(nameSpinner.getSelectedItem());
        currentName = cc.getString(cc.getColumnIndex("name"));
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM grain WHERE name = '" + currentName + "' AND origin = '" + currentOrigin + "'";
        Cursor data = database.rawQuery(sql, null);
        data.moveToFirst();

        int nameColumn = data.getColumnIndex("name");
        int loviColumn = data.getColumnIndex("lovibond");
        int gravityColumn = data.getColumnIndex("gravity");
        int originColumn = data.getColumnIndex("origin");

        String currentIngredientName = data.getString(nameColumn);
        String currentIngredientLovi = data.getString(loviColumn);
        String currentIngredientGravity = data.getString(gravityColumn);
        String currentIngredientOrigin = data.getString(originColumn);

        addIngredient = new String[4];
        addIngredient[0] = currentIngredientName;
        addIngredient[1] = currentIngredientLovi;
        addIngredient[2] = currentIngredientGravity;
        addIngredient[3] = currentIngredientOrigin;



GrainSpinnerAdapter.toggleRadio();
    }
```

LogCat is giving me a nullexpression error at:

```
GrainSpinnerAdapter.toggleRadio();
```

and

```
if(!(rb.isChecked())){
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your question is as simple as it seems (merely changing the state of the radio button upon spinner selection) you can call the toggle() method on your radio button which will invert the radio button's state. you can also declare your RadioButton and call an isChecked method.

```
RadioButton myRadioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.My_RadioButton);

public void YourSpinnerItemMethod () {
    if ( !(myRadioButton.isChecked()) )
         myRadioButton.toggle();
}
```

EDIT:

```
OnSelectedItemChange {
  YOUR_CODE;
  Class_Containing_Radio_Button.toggleButton();
}

Class_Containing_Radio_Button.class {
  RadioButton myButton;

  toggleButton() {
    myButton.toggle();
  }

  onCreate() {
    myButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R........);
  }
}
```

then you can also have a method that reacts to the RadioButton's check state using the isChecked() method. Good Luck!

Comment: I guess the only not so simple part of it is that the spinners OnSelectedItemChanged listener resides in an activity and the radio button is called through a separate adapter class. I haven't been able to figure out how to change the toggle from within another class. I updated my question to include the OnSelectedItemChanged method code.

Comment: why dont you create a method in the class containing the radio button that toggles said button that you can call from your OnSelectedItemChanged? Ill edit my post with some sudo code:

Comment: I accept the answer because I know your right, but its still throwing me a null exception error from within the activity where the OnSelectedItemChanged method is. Am I not referencing the toggleButton method correctly? I updated my ? with new code.

Comment: well, thank you for the accept, could you show me your OnSelectedItemChanged code? this is a method native to android injected with your code correct? also, look at your logcat and see exactly where the null pointer is being called.

Comment: well it is definitely an issue that rb (your radiobutton) is being defined in your newDropDownView code, as once the function returns you have no reference to it. in your toggle code try replacing rb with view.rb or whatever you refer to your new view as.rb

Comment: @ryandlf let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1883/discussion-between-adam-storm-and-ryandlf)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did it...

First of all if you are using SimpleCursorAdapter you dont need to provide a full implementation (newView) that inflates views - it does it for you. If you need to do that, then you should be deriving from CursorAdapter. Anyway...

- In your XML for an item, use a CheckedTextView for the radio button (this is what the Android spinner uses)
- On your adapter expose a SelectedItemPosition property
- In the adapter override BindView() and set the check state of CheckedTextView based on the current selected item position
- In the activity, call the setter to set the adapter SelectedItemPosition whenever needed

I'm not sure how the Android system manages the check state of their view without having a selected item position on the adapter so I'm apparently missing something but this worked for me.